# Как определить наличие цикла в неориентированном графе?

Tags: алгоритм, графы

Как можно узнать, содержит ли неориентированный граф `G(V, E)` цикл за `O(|V|)`? Достаточно выяснить факт наличия цикла без его вывода.

Comment: Терзают меня смутные сомнения, что без просмотра ребер это не получится...

Comment: @Harry из вопроса не следует, что ни одно ребро не должно быть просмотрено, если что

Comment: Должно быть просмотрено не более О(1) ребер для каждой вершины, нет?

Comment: Топологическая сортировка, которая откажет при наличии цикла, тоже работает за `O(|V|+|E|)`...

Comment: За что минус вопросу?

Comment: видимо анонимный минусатор хотел бы узнать, а почему возникла такая необходимость

Comment: как по мне, то зависимость от кол-ва ребер  алгоритма должна  быть очевидной. Поэтому и возникает вопрос. Если такое спросили на собеседовании - это одно, если самому захотелось - другое.

Comment: @KoVadim это задание в книге, так что решение должно быть

Comment: приводите название книги и номер страницы. Он у Кнута было "докажите теорему Ферма (это о a^n+b^n = c^n верно только для n=2). Ну как  бы доказательства уже есть, но оно явно не для читателей этой книги.

Comment: @KoVadim не зря проверил последнее издание -- в моём опечатка. На самом деле граф неориентированный, тогда вопрос закрыт

Comment: так что, я даже книгу угадал?

Comment: @KoVadim почти, Introduction to algorithms, Cormen et al, только я смотрел 2 издание на русском, а сейчас проверил 3 в оригинале и там уже undirected, возможно ошибка перевода (у Кнута не бывает опечаток :))

Comment: русские переводы всегда нужно проверять по оригиналам. иначе можно выучить не то. Я до сих пор помню, как функции почему то кричали (call) :)

Comment: @warmonger, минус могли поставить за неразборчивость в указании языка программирования

Comment: @AlexRudenko любой C-подобный язык подойдёт просто, можно и псевдокодом. Указал самые популярные для большего охвата аудитории

Comment: а не нужно "указать побольше для охвата аудитории". Есть алгоритмы, есть графы. Этого предостаточно

Comment: Так какой ответ? Можно узнать?

Answer (score 1):

Сдаётся мне после поправки на "неориентированный", что дело в следующем - неорграф, не имеющий циклов, является **деревом**.

А у дерева количество рёбер на единицу меньше количества узлов. Поэтому для каждого из компонентов графа должно выполняться соотношение `E<V` - это можно проверить любым обходом.

В данном случае (не обходим все рёбра, если их много, а останавливаемся на V-ом):

```
O(V + E) = O(V+V) = O(V)
```